# How to fix 'Error: Cannot find module 'supertest''

Tags: node.js, supertest

I am new to nodejs. I got one nodejs application and i was just trying to run the tests this app contains. So i tried to run npm test command after installing all packages using npm install. But npm test is throwing below error always

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'supertest'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
```

I tried to uninstall and install supertest but it did not help. I see there is no node_modules folder inside supertest. Would that be an issue? How do we fix it?

Here is the file which is using supertest

```
var fs = require('fs')
var request = require('supertest')

var config = require('./config').getConfig()
var url = config.url

var caCert
if (config.caCertFile) {
  caCert = fs.readFileSync(config.caCertFile)
}

var preparedRequest = function () {
  return caCert ? request.agent(url, { ca: caCert }) : request(url)
}

module.exports = preparedRequest
```

Comment: Did you try `npm install supertest `?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `supertest` is not in your package.json depencendies. So If you run `npm install`, it will not install `supertest`.

Just run `npm install supertest` to install `supertest`, or `npm install --save supertest` to install it and add the dependency in your package.json so the next time you run `npm install` it will install `supertest` too :)